# How to compile and build spark examples into jar?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

So I am editing MovieLensALS.scala and I want to just recompile the examples jar with my modified MovieLensALS.scala.

I used `build/mvn -pl :spark-examples_2.10 compile` followed by `build/mvn -pl :spark-examples_2.10 package` which finish normally. I have `SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES=1` set.

But when I re-run MovieLensALS using `bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.MovieLensALS examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar --rank 5 --numIterations 20 --lambda 1.0 --kryo data/mllib/sample_movielens_data.txt` I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` even though all I added to MovieLensALS.scala is a println saying that this is the modified file, with no other modifications whatsoever.

My scala version is 2.11.8 and spark version is 1.4.0 and I am following the discussion on [this](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-incrementally-compile-spark-examples-using-mvn-td19014.html) thread to do what I am doing.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: `spark-examples-1.4.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar` is the JAR file. Can you show the scala file?

Comment: it is the same MovieLensALS.scala that comes with spark with `println("*************************MODIFIED MOVIELENSALS*********************")` added right after the main.

Comment: Alright, I haven't used that code before, but if that is all you added, can you undo and see if you are getting the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out myself. I compiled using `mvn compile -rf :spark-examples_2.10` followed by `mvn package -rf :spark-examples_2.10` to generate the .jar file. Note that the jar file produced here is `spark-examples-1.4.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar`.

On the other hand, the stackoverflow error was because of a long lineage. For that I could either use checkpoints of reduce numiterations, I did the later. I followed [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10319) for it.